# resultset contains int8 type column however neither getInt or getByte is able to fettch the value of column

Tags: java, postgresql, int, byte, resultset

I am connecting to a postgresql DB and am trying to fetch the count of specific employees

this is the query I am using

select count(*) from new_employees where joining_date between '10-01-2019' AND '11-01-2019'

this query is correctly giving count as 20

[image]

Now I tried connecting the same DB via my groovy script and

on resultset I fetched the values by this

```
int countOfEmployees =  rs.getInt("count");
```

and when I printed the value it gave out correctly as 20

However when I was trying to connect the same DB using Java the value is showing up as 0

I use the same code

```
int countOfEmployees =  rs.getInt("count");
```

but if is of no help

I also tried and checked if resultset is non empty and also found out that the **count column is of type int8** by using resulsetmetadata

```
ResultsetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
System.out.println("Type: " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
```

Even using getByte was of no use I tried capturing the value in a variable and then tried converting it to int still the value was zero.

```
Byte countOfEmp = rs.getByte("count");
int countOfEmpConverted = countOfEmp.intValue();
```

If anyone knows if I am doing something wrong, please help!

Comment: `int8` is a [`biginteger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)- a `long` in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int8` maps to `long` type in Java.
It may be confusing because in programming languages like `C#` we use `int64` and `int32` for `long` and `int` respectively.

Source:
1. [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTikkkxN+-UUiGVTzj8jdfS4PdpB8_tDONMFHNqHk@mail.gmail.com)
2. [here](https://github.com/tada/pljava/wiki/Default-type-mapping)